# Put all text of elements in array jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, text, each

I am getting the `.text()` of all `<li>` elements if the `input` has the `class` actief. It `console.log` it like this when for example the following ones has class actief in it.

```
Example 1
Example 3
Example 5
```

But when I put it in a `variable` in something to print it it only prints:
`Example 5`

I want it to print it like it does in the `console.log`.

```js
$("li").each(function () {
  if ($(this).find("input").hasClass("actief")) {
    content = $(this).find("span.titel").text();
    console.log(content);
  }
});

console.log(content);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li><span class="titel">Example 1</span><input class="actief" /></li>
<li><span class="titel">Example 2</span><input/></li>
<li><span class="titel">Example 3</span><input class="actief" /></li>
<li><span class="titel">Example 4</span><input/></li>
<li><span class="titel">Example 5</span><input class="actief" /></li>
</ul>
```

I want the second `console.log();` to not only print `Example 5` but print this:

```
Example 1
Example 3
Example 5
```

Comment: You should declare that variable outside the loop and keep  appending data to that.

Comment: Please create a minimal, concrete, and verifiable example. Based on your code I cannot reproduce your issue at all: https://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/bur0j8e2/

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to do that haha

Comment: Hi, I made a jsfiddle for you. You see in the first console.log(); it goes right because it is in the loop. In the second `console.log();` I want to echo the 3 with class actief beneath each other in one `console.log();`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zhgyakrs/1/

Comment: I editted my question with the desired output

Comment: You are overwriting `content` variable every iteration

Comment: How can I add a string to a variable every iteration?

Comment: `content += 'new content here';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map()` instead to get the array and use `:has` selector to filter the applicable `<li>`

```js
var textArray = $("li:has(.actief) span.titel").map(function () {
  return $(this).text();      
}).get();

console.log(textArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li><span class="titel">Example 1</span><input class="actief" /></li>
<li><span class="titel">Example 2</span><input/></li>
<li><span class="titel">Example 3</span><input class="actief" /></li>
<li><span class="titel">Example 4</span><input/></li>
<li><span class="titel">Example 5</span><input class="actief" /></li>
</ul>
```